# Display the label AND choices on same line in Shiny radioButtons

Tags: r, shiny, radio-button, label

I would like both the label AND the choices to be displayed on the same line in radioButtons in Shiny.

I have tried:

```
tags$div(tags$span(radioButtons("id",label = "Label:",choices = c("All "="all","Option One"="option1","Option Two"="option2"),inline=TRUE)))
```

with and without the "tags$div(tags$span(" piece.

I would like the result to be:

```
Label: ()All ()Option One () Option two
```

Instead, i am still getting

```
 Label:
 ()All ()Option One () Option two
```

Comment: I'd suggest adding images to improve clarity of the post. Should be easy in paint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `float: left`

So it will be something like:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(
      HTML(
        "
        label{
          float:left;
        }
      "
      ))),

      radioButtons("id1",label = "Label:",choices = c("All "="all","Option One"="option1","Option Two"="option2"),inline=TRUE)

)

server <- function(input, output) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Would a new variable with concatenated information work?

Something like:

```
 df$labelNew<-paste(df$var,"",df$choices)
```

Comment: You may have misunderstood the question. OP is asking for UI where label appears to the left of choices instead of the standard where label is on top of choices.

Comment: @Shree you are correct. i am trying to see if there is a way to change the default behavior of radioButtons so as to show the label to the left of the choices.